# Segmentation fault when running a script with Octave on macOS

Tags: macos, octave

I'm getting a segmentation fault when running a script with Octave 5.2.0 on macOS. Is it something wrong with my sample (which works from within octave), or the way I'm running the script or is it a bug from Octave on macOS ?

```
octave BlackBody.m 
fatal: caught signal Segmentation fault: 11 -- stopping myself...
[1]    95607 segmentation fault  octave BlackBody.m
```

Sample:

```
% simple model of the black body using MATLAB/Octave/Freemat
wavelength = 0.01:0.01:5.0;     % microns sweep over a range of wavelengths
T = 5000;                       % temperature in kelvin
F = 3.742./ ((wavelength.^5).*(exp(1.439e4./(wavelength*T))-1)) ; % gives the result in W/m2/um x 1e8
plot(wavelength,F);
xlabel('wavelength (\mum)');       %  add axis labels and plot title
ylabel('spectral intensity (W/m^2/\mum) x 10^8');
title('Blackbody Radiation');
legend(sprintf('T = %.0f K',T));
```

Comment: Did you run the script line by line, to see which one causes the crash? That might help figure out the problem. Could be the graphics part, for example, which you could circumvent by changing the graphics back end.

Comment: I can't see anything off from that snippet, nor can I reproduce the problem on linux. Can I confirm that what you're saying is, if you save the above snippet as "BlackBody.m" and try to run via "octave BlackBody.m", then this reproduces the problem?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?